# How to simplify a variable's fraction value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, fractions

I have a variable called `b` who's value is determined as so: `b = float(input("What is your y-intercept?"))`. Later in the file, I want to take the value of `b` (assuming it is a float) and convert it to a fraction like this: `print(Fraction(b))`. I know that something like `print(Fraction(0.45))` will print `8106479329266893/18014398509481984`, but `print(Fraction('0.45'))` will print `9/20`. How can I have that same result with a variable? Doing `print(Fraction('b'))` gives me this error: `ValueError: Invalid literal for Fraction: 'b'`.

Code:

```
from fractions import Fraction

elif equation == 'slope':    
    slope = input("Do you need to find slope? Type 'yes' or 'no'.")

    if slope == 'yes':
       y2 = float(input("What's your y2 value?:"))
       y1 = float(input("What is your y1 value?"))
       x2 = float(input("What is your x2 value?:"))
       x1 = float(input("What is your x1 value?:"))

        m = y2-y1/x2-x1
        print(str(m))
    elif slope == 'no':
        m = input("What is the slope?")

    b = float(input("What is your y-intercept?"))
    m = str(m)
    b = str(b)
    print("Your equation is: y = {}x + {}".format(m,b))
    simplify = input("Do you want to simplify this to standard form? Type in 'yes' or 'no'")

    if simplify == 'yes':
        m = float(m)
        b = float(b)
        if m < 0:
            pos_m = m*-1
        if isinstance(b, float):
            print(Fraction(b)) #Works, but not what I want
            print(Fraction('b')) #Does not work
```

Comment: you could try `Fraction(str(b))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Fraction(str(b))
```

This is how you convert the variable's *value* (rather than its *name) to a string.

Answer (score 0):

As @Prune mentioned you have to convert the variable's value to a string, one alternative is using an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/):

```
from fractions import Fraction
b = 0.45
print(Fraction(f'{b}'))
```

The suggested documentation solution is to use [limit_denominator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator):

```
b = 0.45
print(Fraction(b).limit_denominator())
```

**Output**

```
9/20
```

For more on floating point see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `print(Fraction('b'))` doesn't work is because you're asking python to create a fraction out of the character 'b'. What you need to do is get the string representation of b which would be str(b), so `Fraction(str(b))`

Answer (score -2):

Why are you using a float variable? Its better to use an int() function to simply the answer. Creates a whole number rather than adding a decimal.